# Sharepoint Document collaboration

Tags: sharepoint

**Document collaboration**
Is this possible to restrict the section in document, based on the user.
Egg:
 Document contains three sections, 
    Section 1, Section 2, Section 3
 Three users need to contribute for document preparation,
 User 1 for section 1
 User 2 for section 2
 User 3 for section 3.

Thanks,
Gunasekaran Sambandhan

Comment: I own permissions management in SharePoint. I'm not quite sure what you're asking here.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

SharePoint is only able to set permissions for discrete objects (lists, libraries, sites, documents, etc.) and is unable to segment an individual file.

We do two different things here at work to deal with this type of need. We either create a library for a given document then have individual files for each section (this is also useful for collaborating on huge documents even if you don't need to restrict access per section) or we create individual libraries for the sections. The latter is a better way to go for security because it reduces the risk that someone will create a doc and not set permissions.

FWIW: I did a quick check to see if Word would allow me to DRM sections of a document, the answer is no.

Cheers,
Reeves

Comment: thanks for your response, I think am going in a correct direction (am doing the same what you have suggested)

Answer (score 1):

SharePoint has no clue what is actually in the document (other than indexing for search).

To do what you want, you would have to break the document up into 3 different documents and use item level permissions on each, or put each part in a seperate document library that already has the permission levels set to correspond to the user(s) you want to be able to contribute to that part.

Comment: thanks for your response, I have done the same process what you have suggested

Answer (score 0):

HI,

SharePoint limits all collaboration and security features to the Document level.
A solution we have used with some success is to have 3 document libraries with one user given access on each.
A Quick Part is present in the documents in these libraries which pulls information in a Document Library Column. 
A fourth document library has 3 lookup colums pulling information from the aboove 3 Document Library columns 
This can be linked to a single document using Quickparts again.

Kind regards,